# Max prime number in an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

My task is to find the max prime number in an array. My code does not work for numbers with more than one digit. The function only returns the first digit in that case. I guess I have some problem with pointer?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int maxprime(int* array, int size)
{
  int max=0,i,j,a,counter=0;
  for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    a=array[i];
    for(j=2;j<a;j++){
      if(a%j==0) break;
      counter++;
    }
    if(counter==a-2) {
      if(a>max)
    max=a;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

int main()
{
  int array[10] = {225, 224, 223, 226};                                                             
  printf("%d", maxprime(array, 4));
}
```

Comment: Where is `niz` defined in your `printf` call

Comment: The counter variable is irrelevant, if you make it through the `j` loop you've found a prime number.

Comment: @JacobFaib I have fixed the mistake

Comment: Might save you a bit of CPU time to sort the input array largest to smallest, then do your prime check.  Don't need to track max prime that way either.

Comment: Ahh where's the user [largest_prime_is_463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728) when ya need them? ;)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the other response, your `counter` variable is pointless. All you need to do is check that you exited your innermost loop via the `break`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int maxprime(int* array, int size)
{
  int max=0;
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    /* assume every number is prime */
    bool prime=true;
    int a=array[i];
    for(int j=2;j<a;j++){
      if(a%j==0) {
        /* was divisible, so not prime after all */
        prime=false;
        break;
      }
    }
    /* only update max if you found a prime */
    if (prime) max=a>max?a:max;
  }                                                                                                 
  return max;
}
```

Comment: Use `for (int j = 2; j * j <= a; j++)` for the loop control to dramatically reduce the number of pointless tests in the inner loop. It would be better to create an `is_prime()` function that encapsulates the prime hunting, leaving `maxprime()` to coordinate the iterating over the array and finding the maximum prime value. In the `is_prime()` function, you can simply return false as soon as you find a factor. If there are no factors (the loop exits), you return true because the number is prime.

Comment: @JacobFaib But, if I put counter=0 at the beginning of for loop my code would be correct, right?